# Detect dropdown change in JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, drop-down-menu, attributes

In jsp, is there any attribute to provide the information that values in the dropdown got changed?

Say Example:

I have dropdown country - On page load it have "US" in the dropdown and I'm changing to "UK" and then again changing to "US". In this case I have not done any change so I have nothing to save but if I click save button my page is getting submitted. Is there anyway to avoid this page submission.?

Comment: JSP is a server side language. I don't think you can really do that without a client side language like Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. But you have to use `javascript`, not `jsp`. Example code

html:

```
<form class="checked">
    <input type="hidden" id="countrySelectInitial" value="UK" /> <!-- we need this element to store initial value --> 
    <select name="country" class="checkedInput" id="countrySelect">
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="UK" selected>UK</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" class="submitButton" disabled />
</form>
```

js:

```
$(".checkedInput").change(function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    var idValue = $(this).attr('id'); // we need id to retrieve initial value. Initial value is stored in element with id <id>Initial
    var oldValue = $("#" + idValue + "Initial").val();
    if(newValue === oldValue) {
            // if value don't changed - disable button. user have no possibility to submit form
        $(this).parents("form.checked").find(".submitButton").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
            // if value changed - remove "disabled" attribute. User can click button and submit form
        $(this).parents("form".checked).find(".submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```